# Using the python quickfix package, how can I send a TestRequest message?

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have an established FIX connection with a vendor and we are sending heartbeats every thirty seconds. However, due to their system setup, they send me TestRequests `(35=1)` at varying intervals along with the heartbeats. I have never had to handle these and the quickfix package is interpreting them as heartbeats. However, this is causing their systems to log me out.

A sample of the messages when I first logon is as follows:

```
2017-09-05 11:50:47,769 - fix_connection.FIX_IO - INFO - toAdmin >>>>:
8=FIX.4.2|9=78|35=A|34=1|49=***|52=20170905-15:50:47.763|56=XXX|98=0|108=30|141=Y|10=111|

2017-09-05 11:50:48,361 - fix_connection.FIX_IO - INFO - fromAdmin >>>>:
8=FIX.4.2|9=77|35=A|34=1|43=N|49=XXX|52=20170905-15:50:55.062|56=***|98=0|108=30|10=043|

2017-09-05 11:50:48,421 - fix_connection.FIX_IO - INFO - fromAdmin >>>>:
8=FIX.4.2|9=89|35=1|34=2|43=N|49=XXX|52=20170905-15:50:55.119|56=***|112=05/09/2017-11:50:55|10=163|

2017-09-05 11:50:48,437 - fix_connection.FIX_IO - INFO - toAdmin >>>>:
8=FIX.4.2|9=84|35=0|34=2|49=***|52=20170905-15:50:48.428|56=XXX|112=05/09/2017-11:50:55|10=175|

2017-09-05 11:51:18,644 - fix_connection.FIX_IO - INFO - fromAdmin >>>>:
8=FIX.4.2|9=65|35=0|34=3|43=N|49=XXX|52=20170905-15:51:25.341|56=***|10=254|

2017-09-05 11:51:18,657 - fix_connection.FIX_IO - INFO - toAdmin >>>>:
8=FIX.4.2|9=60|35=0|34=3|49=***|52=20170905-15:51:18.649|56=XXX|10=019|
```

I have already searched for a way to send a TestRequest specifically using the quickfix package, but didn't find anything. Can someone point me in the right direction or provide an example? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple piece of code, written in c#. Please check with your vendor the data to send correctly (the "test" in my example).

`sessionId` is the Session object with the parameters between you and the counterparty.

```
public void SendTestRequestMessage() {
        QuickFix42.TestRequest req = new QuickFix42.TestRequest();
        req.set(new TestReqID("test"));
        Session.sendToTarget(req, sessionId);

    }
```